# finding difficulty in setting up redis for my node.js application

Tags: node.js, redis, queue, backend, bull

my application connected well with the local machine host using redis but i find difficulties while connecting with cloud hosted redis. I have also tried making redis data base on render and redis entriprise website.
I have tried:

```
import Redis from 'ioredis'

const redis = new Redis({
    host: '<host>',
    port: 13280,
    password: '<password>'
});
```

```
import Redis from 'ioredis'
(async () => {
  // Connect to your internal Redis instance using the REDIS_URL environment variable
  // The REDIS_URL is set to the internal Redis URL e.g. redis://red-343245ndffg023:6379
  const client = createClient({
      url: '<host_url>'
  });

  client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

  await client.connect();

  // Send and retrieve some values
  await client.set('key', 'node redis');
  const value = await client.get('key');

  console.log("found value: ", value)
})();
```

This function works fine with my local machine with redis-server hosted locally
with port: 6379
Function that use redis dependency:

```
import Queue from "bull";
import Job from "../models/codesubmission.js";
import participantStatus from "../models/participantstatus.js"
import {executeCpp, executeCppWithOutputFile} from "../executecode/Cpp.js";
import {executePy} from "../executecode/Py.js"
import fs from "fs/promises"
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

// const jobQueue = new Queue("job-runner-queue");
const jobQueue = new Queue("job-runner-queue");
const NUM_WORKERS = 5;

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname= path.dirname(__filename);
console.log("dirname",__dirname)
const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, "outputs");

jobQueue.process(NUM_WORKERS, async ({ data }) => {
  console.log("data",data)
  const jobId = data.id;
  const job = await Job.findById(jobId);
  console.log("ppp", job)
  if (job === undefined) {
    throw Error(`cannot find Job with id ${jobId}`);
  }
  try {
    let output1, output2, output3;
    job["startedAt"] = new Date();
    if (job.language === "cpp") {
      console.log("executeCpp");
      output1 = await executeCpp(job.filepath);
      (async () => {
        try {
          await fs.unlink(job.filepath);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      })();
      output2= await executeCppWithOutputFile("t2");
      output3= await executeCppWithOutputFile("t3");
      console.log(output1, getDifference(output1, data.r1))
      console.log(output2, getDifference(output2, data.r2));
      console.log(output3, getDifference(output3, data.r3))
      
      //delete here
    } else if (job.language === "py") {
      output1 = await executePy(job.filepath);
      //delete here
    }
    // job["completedAt"] = new Date();
    job["res1"] = getDifference(output1, data.r1)===0? true: false;
    job["res2"] = getDifference(output2, data.r2)===0? true: false;
    job["res3"] = getDifference(output3, data.r3)===0? true: false;

    if(job["res1"]===false || job["res2"]===false || job["res3"]===false){
      job["status"] = "error";
    }
    else{
      job["status"] = "success";
    }
  
    console.log(job);
    await job.save();


    
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    job["completedAt"] = new Date();
    job["output"] = JSON.stringify(err);
    job["status"] = "error";
    console.log(job);
    await job.save();
    throw Error(JSON.stringify(err));
  }
});

jobQueue.on("failed", (error) => {
  console.error(error.data.id, error.failedReason);
});

function getDifference(a, b) {
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var result = 0;
    var as= a.length, bs= b.length;
    if(as!= bs) return -1;
    while (i< as && j< bs) {
      if (a[i] != b[j])
        result ++;
      i++;
      j++;
    }
    return result;
}

export const addJobToQueue = async (jobId, t1, t2, t3, r1, r2, r3, contestid, userid, problemnumber) => {
  console.log(jobId);
  await jobQueue.add({
    id: jobId,
    t1: t1,
    t2: t2,
    t3: t3,
    r1: r1,
    r2: r2,
    r3: r3,
    contestid: contestid,
    userid: userid,
    problemnumber: problemnumber,
  });
};
```

I have also tried to connect using render provided docs for nodejs:

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';

(async () => {
  // Connect to your internal Redis instance using the REDIS_URL environment variable
  // The REDIS_URL is set to the internal Redis URL e.g. redis://red-343245ndffg023:6379
  const client = createClient({
      url: process.env.REDIS_URL
  });

  client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

  await client.connect();

  // Send and retrieve some values
  await client.set('key', 'node redis');
  const value = await client.get('key');

  console.log("found value: ", value)
})();
```

Is that redis needed to use bulls or I am at wrong direction...

Thanks in advance for your time and solution!

Comment: Could you share error logs or something else about the error itself?

Comment: Are you using Node Redis or ioredis? The import on your second block of code clearly says ioredis but the code therein is using the syntax needed to connect to Node Redis.

Comment: Also, the third block of code doesn't mention Redis at all as far as I can tell.

Comment: how can i set up Redis dependency for bull working?

Comment: @GuyRoyse third block doesn't need redis importing, it works with the Redis server running on my local machine. But I want to deploy my application, any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

```
const jobQueue = new Queue("job-runner-queue", 
{ redis: { port: 13280, host: 'host-address', password: '<password' 
}} );

jobQueue.on('error', (error) => {
  console.log(error);
})
```